# How to read Unread mail in Pop3 automatically using android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

I need to read and send email from pop3 server (Rackspace) I have done reading and writing for gmail. I am facing two problem 
1. how to read email from Pop3 server (Rackspac, yahoo, live, Unread only not every).
2. when i read email from gmail first time there is no issue when i try to read second time it is saying Connection is open while i am closing connection properly every time if i restart my application it works for first time smoothly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The POP3 protocol doesn't provide any support for flags that tell you whether a message is new or unread.  See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).
2. Clearly you're doing something wrong.  [Turn on session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and the protocol trace will show whether you're really closing the folder.